# camera movement for game?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Ok ive setup some keyboard movements for forward, backwards, turning left, turning right. But what I want is when I move my mouse I would like my camera to pan to the right, left, up, or down some. Think about the movement controls in minecraft if that helps any.

Comment: It looks like [**this addon**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/FPS_Mouselook) or [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWi1_sh9pno) might help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **mouse** actuator on your camera.

*delay>and>Mouse, mouse look.*

Set the delay to 0.01 and enable *true-level-triggering* this will behave as an *always* sensor, but delay works better with mouse look. The delay will read 0 but it really will work for 0.01 frames.
Create a mouse actuator and set the type to **mouse look**.
You can specify how you want the mouse to look in the properties of the actuator. Basically, if it's turning too far when you move your mouse, increase the min. value and decrease the **max.** value.

[image]